# Extract rows from dataframe of the last date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, pivot

I have got a dataframe 'df' with a column 'HIST_DATUM' containing the end of each month. Let's say from 31.12.2021, 31.01.2022 ... until 31.07.2022
Do you know a code which extracts to a new dataframe 'df2' the rows from the last date, which would be in my example: all rows cointaining the date = 31.07.2022 in column date.
Thank you for your reply

Comment: Can you post a sample input and output please?

Comment: It should be something like this VVslastDatapoint=VVs.loc[VVs['HIST_DATUM']==lastDate]

Comment: Convert 'HIST_DATUM' to datetime objects if needed and use `max` to get the latest date.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would convert the column to the Datetime data type:

```
df["HIST_DATUM"]=pd.to_datetime(df["HIST_DATUM"], format="%d.%m.%Y")
```

Then you can extract the rows with the most recent ("max") date:

```
df2=df[df["HIST_DATUM"]==df["HIST_DATUM"].max()]
```